# I'm a really tiny critter. Come close

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Come really close and take a look at me.

> May be you will think I am sleepy
>
> May be you will have a couple of questions:
>
> *Why* is he far away at the end?
>
> *Why* are there six in a row then one?
>
> You might find me creepy
>
> So be it. I like my unique place.

Can you tell me who I am?

Hint

> A 7 letter word

Comment: Is the space between "May" and "be" intentional?

Comment: No the space is not intentional

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an interesting word

> Zyzzyva

A 7 letter word

> Last word in the dictionary!
>
>  A very tiny beetle no longer than an ant
>
>  Several ZZZ s--- sleepy
>
>  A couple of "y"s
>
>  Six consonants in a row
>
>  And it creeps along

A fun word if you ask me.